# Django Rest how to get multiple objects with lookup_field

Tags: python-3.x, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to create simple filtering for my api. What I want to search in my url is:
/api/videoquestionset/2/

And get **every** videoquestion object that has the video field with 2 or any other number, depending on what the devs request.

The error I get right now is:
`get() returned more than one VideoQuestions -- it returned 2!`

Here is my code:

models.py

```
    class Questions(models.Model):
    """
        Questions class for the e-learner overlay
    """
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    answer = models.OneToOneField(QuestionAnswers, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                  related_name='correct_answer', null=True, blank=True)
    choices = models.ManyToManyField(QuestionAnswers, related_name='choices')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Questions"


class VideoQuestions(models.Model):
    """
        Categorize questions per video
    """
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    question = models.ManyToManyField(Questions, blank=True, related_name='question')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "learner questions"
```

views.py:

```
class VideoQuestionSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = VideoQuestionSerializer
    queryset = VideoQuestions.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'video'

    # def get_queryset(self):
    #     queryset = VideoQuestions.objects.all()
    #     video = self.request.query_params.get('video', None)
    #     if video is not None:
    #         queryset = queryset.filter(video=video)
    #     return queryset
```

my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from rest_framework import routers

from .views import VideoQuestionsListView, VideoQuestionSet



router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'videoquestions', VideoQuestionsListView, basename='vq-list'),
router.register(r'videoquestionset', VideoQuestionSet, basename='vq-detail'),


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include(router.urls))
]
```

What I tried:

- Django filtering with regex, like /videoquestionset/?v=2. I could not really figure filtering out, so I reverted back to my old code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer URL filtering in your case (you already have).

```
class VideoQuestionSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = VideoQuestionSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = VideoQuestions.objects.all()
        video = self.request.query_params.get('video', None)
        if video:
            queryset = queryset.filter(video_id=int(video))
        return queryset
```

Please note that, remove the **`lookup_field`** as well as **`queryset`** attributes from your view.

In the *new view*, we are looking for a URL query parameter named **`video`**. So, while filtering the results, your URL must be as

```
/videoquestionset/?video=2
```

In short, your approach was correct, but you have tried the wrong URL.

Comment: Wow it being so simple, really bugs me. I was pulling my hairs because of this. Thank you so much sir!